# Giving an Id to an Item in a for loop

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, model, controller

Guys I am generating a series of textboxes with a button next to it(in an li tag) as

```
 <div class="col-md-10">
            <ul id="sortable" style="list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0;">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.BulletPoints.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <li class="ui-state-default" style="margin-bottom: 8px;"><span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BulletPoints[i], new { @maxlength = "200", @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 825px;max-width: 90%;" }) <div style="width: 70px; max-width: 10%; margin-top: -30px; float: right;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" style="margin-top: 4px; float: left;"></span> <input type="button" style="float: right;" value="X" onclick="SubmitForm('deletebullet')" /></div></span></li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Note BulletPoints is as   `public List<string> BulletPoints { get; set; }` in the model.

However now I have to remove any of these textbox by clicking the button next to it.

Any help of how to implement this ?

Comment: can you show your html which rendered?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad , see edits.

Answer (score 3):

```
<ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.BulletPoints.Count(); i++)
    {
     <li class="ui-state-default" style="margin-bottom: 8px;"><span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BulletPoints[i], new { @maxlength = "200", @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 825px;max-width: 90%;" }) <div style="width: 70px; max-width: 10%; margin-top: -30px; float: right;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" style="margin-top: 4px; float: left;"></span> <input type="button" style="float: right;" value="X" onclick="SubmitForm(this)" /></div></span></li>
    }
</ul>
<script>
    function SubmitForm(obj) {      
        $(obj).parent().siblings().remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I need to delete the corresponding string from the List in the model too. How do I achieve this part ?

Comment: Yes it works always until you damage html structure.